# Old AngularJS controller not unloading

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I'm having an issue where old controllers seem to stay active, even after using ui-router's `$state.go` function to go to a different state with another controller.

I've tested this by adding an interval to each controller, logging it's name to the console. After changing the state multiple times, all the previously visited controllers stay active:

```
$interval(function () {
   console.info("ACCOUNT")
}, 1000)
```

[image: Console Log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the official documentation [available here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval), intervals created using `$interval` are not automatically destroyed when the controller's scope is destroyed.

> Note: Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed
>   when you are finished with them. In particular they are not
>   automatically destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's
>   element are destroyed. You should take this into consideration and
>   make sure to always cancel the interval at the appropriate moment.

It is a good practice to listen to the scope's `$destroy` event and destroy all the intervals that were created in the controller.

Here is a good way to do it.

```
var intervalRef;

$scope.someFunction = function () {
   // Save a reference to the interval's promise so that it can be canceled later
   intervalRef = $interval(function () {
                   console.info("ACCOUNT")
                 }, 1000);
}

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    // When the scope of the controller is destroyed, cancel the interval
    if (intervalRef) {
        $interval.cancel(intervalRef);  
    } 
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Probably not the best way to debug that then.
But I've found this issue while using $window.onfocus, which still called the old controllers.
Might just be me missing some documentation again, but I couldn't find any information on that.

Comment: Nvm, I used the '$destroy' event to unset the onfocus event.

Comment: Event listeners that are setup using `$scope.$on` will get cleaned up automatically when `$scope` is garbage collected. Every thing else needs to be cleaned up manually.